# Is that possible to upcast erased type without RTTI?

Tags: c++, exception, rtti, type-erasure, std-expected

I have a custom implementation of `std::expected`, but with a type-erased error. It makes the expected type looks similar to exceptions. We just can use the next code:

```
Expected<int> V = 123;
V.SetError(std::string("Error occurred"));
```

And when we try to get the value from `Expected`, we can just output the stored value to screen (if it supports some function overloading for `std::string` or another type that is stored in `Expected`).

I think this is good practice if we don't want to use exceptions.

But, it would also be nice to handle the error by its parent class, similar to a `try`/`catch`:

```
struct MathError{};
struct ZeroDivisionError : MathError{};

Expected V = 321;
V.SetError(ZeroDivisionError{});

if (auto Error = V.Catch<MathError>())
{
   // we go here if error is subclass of MathError
}
```

But, I have disabled RTTI in my project, and now I can't use `dynamic_cast` to upcast the stored error (as `void*`) to `MathError*`.

Ok, I can make an individual type identifier for each type that is used as an error using a static template function (1 instantiated type = 1 type id).

But, in this case, I can only cast to the exact type if their ids are the same. Maybe something like `std::bases` would help me (I could enumerate all the classes and make a list of their ids), but this feature is not available in the standard.

So, is there any chance?

Comment: Upcasting refers to typecasting a child object to a parent object. Downcasting provides casting a parent object to a child object. Casting from void* however is neither. We have to cast exactly to type from what it was cast to void*, regardless if there is RTTI or no.

Comment: Why disable RTTI? Yes, there's a small size overhead and (if used) a small runtime overhead. But it's all negligible on modern hardware.

Comment: Rephrased, your question is can you write code that makes decisions based on the runtime type of an object without compiler-generated runtime type information. Sure; you have to do all the work yourself. That's hard, and error-prone. Why do you want to disable RTTI?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the error type erased in the first place? It isn't in `std::expected` and this type-erasure is the root of your problems.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  
RTTI may not be recommended in the framework context. For example: In UnrealEngine projects RTTI and Exceptions usually disabled.

Comment: @PeteBecker it is better to say: I don't want to enable RTTI for my project.

Comment: @joergbrech I think this is interesting and good (in my opinion) pattern. 
Benefits: 
1. No additional boilerplate template parameter (Error type); 
2. Any error can be setted to this version of `expected` at any time; 
3. Error catching interface that brings closer to C++ exceptions

Comment: @ArtemSelivanov -- RTTI is part of the implementation's support for the C++ programming language. If you want to remove parts of the language, you should be able to explain what benefit you gain from that. "may not be recommended in the framework context" is not an explanation.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think it's about executable size and performance on various platforms. I'm not familiar to each compiler and can't say for sure how rtti can affect on one or other game, but very often every bit matters, especially on non-desktop platforms (ps4). Also ue have own reflection system, it doesn't need rtti

Answer (score 0):

I found good solution to solve it without RTTI

We can declare class that can be caught by using such `expected` interface.

First, declare the base class of `RuntimeError` and add static function that returns type id of itself.

```
class RuntimeError
{
    static set<size_t> GetBaseIds()
    {
        return { TypeId::GetTypeId<RuntimeError>() };
    }
}
```

Next, create a template class that will add some stuff to intermediate parent:

```
template<typename Parent>
class DeriveError : Parent
{
   static set<size_t> GetBaseIds()
   {
      set<size_t> BaseIds = Parent::GetBaseIds();
      BaseIds.insert(TypeId::GetTypeId<Parent>());
      return BaseIds ;
   }
}
```

Now we can derive error from RuntimeError easily.

```
class MathError : DeriveError<RuntimeError> {};
class ZeroDivisionError : DeriveError<MathError> {};
```

Now, when we set error to `expected`, we can send all ids of each error parent class:

```
    template<typename E>
    void SetError(E Error)
    {
        // Erased error handler
        ErrorHandler = make_unique<ErrorHandler<E>>(Error);

        if constexpr (is_base_of_v<RuntimeError, E>)
        {
            set<size_t> Bases = E::GetBaseIds();
            Bases.Add(TypeId::GetTypeId<E>());
            // Send parent ids to error handler
            ErrorHandler->SetBases(Bases);
        }
    }
```

Catch method:

```
    // avoid catching if not derived from RuntimeError
    template<typename E>
    typename enable_if<is_base_of_v<RuntimeError, E>, const E*>::type
    Catch()
    {
        const int32 ErrorTypeId = TypeId::GetTypeId<E>();
        // Error handler can return NULL if ErrorTypeId not matches any type id
        return static_cast<const E*>(ErrorHandler->TryCatchErrorByTypeId(ErrorTypeId));
    }
```

Now we can set and catch errors:

```
Expected Value = 1234;
Value.SetError(ZeroDivisionError>());

if (auto Error = Value.Catch<RuntimeError>())
{
    cout << "Error caught: " << Error.ToString();
}
```